# Giving this formula in DNF and CNF propositional logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, contest-math

The formula I am trying to turn into conjunctive normal form and disjunctive normal form is:

$P \rightarrow (Q \land R)$

could anyone please help me give two answers, CNF and DNF? I have managed to get DNF which turned out to be:

$¬P \lor (Q \land R)$
also is my DNF correct?

Comment: still need help

Answer (score 0):

As you have observed, $A \rightarrow B \equiv \neg A \rightarrow B$, so
$$P \rightarrow (Q \land R) \equiv \neg P \lor (Q \land R),$$
which is in disjunctive normal form. Now use distributivity to get
$$\neg P \lor (Q \land R) \equiv (\neg P \lor Q) \land (\neg P \lor R),$$
which is in conjunctive normal form.